# Cannot change timeseries plot to hourly interval

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I currently have the this graph:
[graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR5R4.png)

I would like to change the x axis to a 1 hour interval. I tried doing so using the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax.scatter(x,y, marker= '|', c= df['colors'])
ax.yaxis.grid()
ax.get_yticklabels()[7].set_color("white")
ax.get_yticklabels()[10].set_color("white")
ax.set_xlim(["05:59:00", "16:59:59"])
hours = mdates.HourLocator(interval = 1)
h_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(h_fmt)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Locator attempting to generate 1903633 ticks from 21540.0 to 61199.0: exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS
```

Not sure how to go about this. Some help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does `hours = mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(24), interval=1)` help?

Comment: @Patol75 I guess not, since that's the default (see [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.HourLocator)) @tahsinac what's the result of `print(x.min(),x.max(),len(x))` ?

Comment: Relevant would also be `type(x)`... so in total, and as usual, one needs a [mcve]!!